# Frobenius matrix norm inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

I have an inequality frobenius matrix norm as follow:

$f(Y) = \|-2YA + BY + CYD\|_F$
$A,B,C,D,Y$ are all matrices, and assume all $R^{n \times n}$.

My goal is to define an upperbound for $f(Y)$, basically, I want to pull out of $Y$

I have an solution as follow
$f(Y) \le \|-2YA\|_F + \|BY\|_F + \|CYD\|_F = \|2Y\|_F\|A\|_F + \|B\|_F\|Y\|_F + \|C\|_F\|Y\|_F\|D\|_F$

As we can get the following:
$f(Y) \le (\|2A\|_F + \|B\|_F + \|C\|_F\|D\|_F)  \times \|Y\|_F$

Am I right for all proof? if not, tell me what's wrong on the inequality chain. Thanks very much.

Comment: What happened to $\|A\|_F$?

Comment: I edit my equation, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f(Y) \le \|-2YA\|_F + \|BY\|_F + \|CYD\|_F \color{red}{\le} \|2Y\|_F\|A\|_F + \|B\|_F\|Y\|_F + \|C\|_F\|Y\|_F\|D\|_F$

By submultiplicative propery of frobenius norm.

In general, $\|AB\|_F \ne \|A\|_F\|B\|_F$

Comment: I got it, And how about the rest of inequality? Is  it true? Thanks so much.

Comment: They seems fine, you can also take the $2$ outside the norm if you want.